# Jboss EAP 6.3.3 (AS 7.4.3 final redhat 2) how to setup periodic size based logging in standalone-full.xml

Tags: logging, jboss

I tried with following setup in standalone-full.xml file but with no luck. Is anything work with below setup? Can any one tell me is Jboss EAP 6.3.3 supports this setup?
Thanks in advance.

```
            <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
                <max-backup-index value="4"/>
                <rotate-size value="100k"/>
                <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
            </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.
The problem is that this was not a standard handler until EAP 6.4.
The solution would be to upgrade to `EAP 6.4.22` at least, and apply.

Comment: Thanks @Francisco Melo Jr. Is there any work around available? As i am not permitted to upgrade EAP version. Appreciate your help.